# Detect the Incoming TCP Packets

Tags: networking, firewall

I am developing a feature in my application for screen mirroring for which I need to open a wide range of ports (approx. 10000 number of ports) in my android system. It is a risk to open all these ports all the time.

I need to know if there is any mechanism to anticipate exactly which port will be used by the Screen Mirroring Server to send these TCP packets, is there any API or listener in AOSP which will be able to listen to the requests from the Server to open a particular port

Comment: Typically some sort of handshake protocol on a fixed port is used to agree on the used prot. I would assume that opening 10000 will fail as there is a limit on maximum open [file] handles that is much lower (and every open port consumes at least one handle). So my recommendation is to get and read the protocol specification of the used screen mirroring protocol.

Comment: I am not sure if in this handshake, the server will send the data regarding the port it will try to connect. Basically I want to avoid opening all the ports and want my server to intimate what port it want to use, so I can open only that port in my firewall